# MySql: Complex Aggregate Query

Tags: mysql

I have the data shown as follows:

```
table: School_Work

ID  Pay_Date    Hours   Amount
1   1/5/2014    5       20
1   1/5/2014    7       30
1   1/5/2014    10      25
1   1/8/2014    15      30
1   1/9/2014    18      25
2   1/7/2014    5       15
2   1/7/2014    5       10
2   1/9/2014    7       15
2   1/9/2014    9       26
2   1/9/2014    10      100
```

I have the following query atm:

```
SELECT ID, min(Pay_Date) as Start_Date, max(Pay_Date) as End_Date, sum(Amount) As Total_Without_Beginning_Start_Date
FROM School_Work
GROUP BY ID
```

The code works fine but I need it to NOT include the Start_Date calculating the Total Amount.

ID 1 should only be

```
30+25
```

ID 2 should only be

```
15+26+100
```

I tried using the having clause also but that didnt work.  Thanks your input~

I need the result to be

```
ID   Start_Date    End_Date   Total_Without_Beginning_Start_Date
1    1/5/2014      1/9/2014   55
2    1/7/2014      1/9/2014   141
```

Comment: So don't include the earliest of each Id ?

Comment: explain a bit more?? I don't get the question

Comment: I need 
ID 1 Date 1/5/2014 not included in the sum(amount) calculation
ID 2 Date 1/7/2014 not included in the sum(amount) calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a sub-query (generally a bad idea, but its fine for lightweight or 1-time queries). Try this...

```
SELECT x.ID, 
       min(x.Pay_Date) as Start_Date, 
       max(x.Pay_Date) as End_Date, 
       sum(x.Amount) - (select sum(y.Amount) from School_Work y where y.ID = x.ID and y.Pay_Date = min(x.Pay_Date) order by y.Pay_Date asc limit 1) As Total_Without_Beginning_Start_Date
FROM School_Work x
GROUP BY x.ID
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a988ec/1 i just ran this on jsfiddle it gave me a result of 110 instead of 55.

Comment: @ParkBroom Ah, ok, sorry! I didn't realize that a day could have multiple IDs. I edited my answer, please try now.